# Golang reverse proxy with custom authentication

Tags: authentication, go, reverse-proxy, middleware

I am trying to authenticate a user by calling a REST api, before I proxy the request to a remote server.
However, I find that if I make the api call before proxy to remote server, the request will fail with the following error:

```
http: proxy error: http: ContentLength=139 with Body length 0.
```

If I remove the api call before proxy to remote server, the request can get through and return correct response.

My middleware is as following:

```
func AuthMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                // the api call to external auth server
        user_id, err := authenticate(r.FormValue("username"), r.FormValue("password"))      
                if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 401)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

My reverse proxy is as following:

```
func NewReverseProxy(target *url.URL) *httputil.ReverseProxy {
    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        req.URL.Scheme = target.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = target.Host
        req.URL.Path = target.Path
        targetQuery := target.RawQuery
        if targetQuery == "" || req.URL.RawQuery == "" {
            req.URL.RawQuery = targetQuery + req.URL.RawQuery
        } else {
            req.URL.RawQuery = targetQuery + "&" + req.URL.RawQuery
        }
        if _, ok := req.Header["User-Agent"]; !ok {
            // explicitly disable User-Agent so it's not set to default value
            req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "")
        }
    }
    return &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
}
```

And I am using Chi for routing

```
r.Use(AuthMiddleware)
r.Post("/", NewReverseProxy(targets).ServeHTTP)
```

What is the issue with this implementation?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is: do you read the body and close it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337891/net-http-http-contentlength-222-with-body-length-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [net/http: http: ContentLength=222 with Body length 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337891/net-http-http-contentlength-222-with-body-length-0)

Comment: @RickyA thanks. I think the `r.FormValue("username")` read the body and close it. If I do need to get these value, what would you suggest? Make a copy of the body? Thank you

Comment: Do you use the body for anything else than sending the credentials?

Comment: Hi @RickyA , no, I use it only for credentials. I plan to move it to header.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care for the body anymore you can set the contentlength of the request to 0, reflecting the current state of the body:

```
func AuthMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // the api call to external auth server
        user_id, err := authenticate(r.FormValue("username"), r.FormValue("password"))
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 401)
            return
        }
        r.ContentLength = 0
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Comment: When using `r.ContentLength = 0` it means that the body would pass through the proxy without any modification? and what would be the difference with `r.ContentLength = -1`?